# cakephp Counter cache in nested model

Tags: cakephp, nested, counter-cache

i have nested model structure

`id

parent_id

counter

name`

how to use automated counter cache

Comment: have you tried the normal way? in the relationship definition...

Comment: yes, i can do it in normal way, but i have excisted nested structure fulled with data.

Comment: Ii did not say 'can you do it the normal way' I said 'have you tried it the normal way' as it should work the normal way

Answer (score 1):

Define it in the relationship definition.

```
<?php

class YourModel extends AppModel {

    var $belongsTo = array(
        'ParentModel' => array(
            'foreignKey' => 'your_model_id',
            'className' => 'ParentModel',
            'counterCache' => 'counter'
            )
        )
    );
}
?>
```

Where 'counter' is the field in your table that contains the count.

Comment: Barry - read the page in the cookbook (or the api) - I don't think you get to pass the field name to the counterCache key. From the docs it seems to be fixed to the name of the related table (pluralized) and with _count appended to it. A quick test shows me that your code as is isn't working as expected.

Comment: From the book: counterCache: If set to true the associated Model will automatically increase or decrease the “[singular_model_name]_count” field in the foreign table whenever you do a save() or delete(). If its a string then its the field name to use. The value in the counter field represents the number of related rows.